# Recurring Billing with Dynamic Amounts month to month

Tags: php, web, recurring-billing

Is there a billing system that exists where I can have recurring billing every month, and change the amount the client is charged each month using code? For example, one month a user uses our service for one week and is charged $10, but the next week they use the service for 3 weeks and are charged $30, then the following month they use it for  weeks and are charged $20. Every system I've looked at you must manually change this value, and I was wondering if there was a system that allowed you to automate this process. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this using the PayPal Website Payments Pro API.  First you create an initial transaction and retain the ID.  Then have a cron run whenever you want to process recurring transactions and process what they call a reference transaction.  You pass it the last transaction ID and give it a new dollar value.  It'll process another transaction with the same information.

Limitations on PayPal's reference transactions are they can't be older than 12 months from the last transaction and I believe the dollar cap is $10,000.